# How to make dashed font?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, fonts, font-recommendation, font-design

I am completely new to graphic design and I need to make dashed Cyrillic letters. The file needs to be in '.ttf' format for the end result.

I am attaching a reference picture to what I mean by 'dashed' letters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You'll need to use font creation software to make TTF fonts. Illustrator and Inkscape alone won't cut it.  Sorry.  Something like FontForge (which is free and Open Source).  You could of course use a vector image editor to create the outlines, and import them into your font software.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done *any* research into font creation?

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr

Comment: @Scott, Yes I tried illustrator, however, only thing I can do is import outline to a font editor. I tried font forge, but some Cyrillic shapes are very complicated so I am struggling to create them in font forge. Thanks!

Comment: You may need something more than freeware -- FontLab or similar.